# Javascript regular expression to remove characters from the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a couple strings like:

```
net_weight_(lbs)
net_height_(inches)
```

I need a regular expression that will remove the `_(x)` from the end of the string.  So in my two examples, I would be left with:

```
net_weight
net_height
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd prefer not to use regular expressions you can use `lastIndexOf('_')` and the get the substring up to that index.

```
s = s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7qrW/

Comment: actually, the regular expression was working for me because sometimes I would just have a string like 'name' and I would then get an empty string returned.  I guess I could check to see if the underscore exists first....